# How to force git to not track the some folders

Tags: windows, git

I faced a weird situation with git and I couldn't find a proper solution. It is a bit more complicated than how I described in title.

I got a new laptop and I just installed git and clone one of my repository from remote. While I was working I noticed that git is tracking my all root user folder as one repository.

[image: The folder that git accept at repository]

You can see the details when I run the "**git status**"

[image: The message after I run git status]

Now the question how I can make git to not track any this folders or basically I delete this  unnecessary repository from git? I already deleted all files about git in this main folder and tried "**git reset**"; but it didn't work.
What can I do?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+Could+not+open+directory+Cookies+Permission+denied

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I fortgot to delete a hidden folder of git

> ".git"

, I just delete this folder and now it is not tracking this folders anymore. There is not any git repository at this directory anymore.

I just answered because someone else might have some problem.